# Read metadata added by Apple Final Cut

Tags: php, metadata, finalcut

I am editing some videos in Final Cut and I would like to make these available on my website. I have added some keywords to the videos. Is there a way I can extract/read these keywords using php scripts?

Is this metadata stored in the same way as ID3 tags? How can the php script read them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to find an API which can handle Apple Final Cut files or to make your own (hard, especially if the format is not open). Otherwise your best bet is to manually enter the keywords to the website.